# Ros2 can not import python modules located in subfolders

Tags: ros2, python, ros-humble

I am new to use ROS. I use Ros2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04. I need to import some python codes/modules from different nested folders (or nested nested folders) to a Ros2 python node. The Ros2 node (`demo_in_ros.py`) is located in `src` folder of my Ros package. I have all other python modules in `src` folder as well. I have imported all python modules to the Ros2 node (`demo_in_ros.py`) using the python `import` function (example: `from utils import common_utils`). The structure of my Ros2 package is below:

```
ros2demo_ws
    |src
        |dl_demo
            |dl_demo
                |demo_in_ros.py
                |utils
                    |common_utils.py
```

I have successfully built the package using `colcon build`. After running `ros2 run dl_demo pub_sub`, I get this error:

```
    from utils import common_utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

How can I solve this issue?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Thanks,

Abbas

Comment: Just a note, `colcon build` doesn't build python code. It will install it as specified in the setup.py file, which it looks like you might be missing.

Comment: Try this "from dl_demo.utils import common_utils" or maybe this "from dl_demo.dl_demo.utils import common_utils" as a test. I had a similar sounding issue in the past that was addressed by beinga bit more specific on the import.

Comment: @proan Thank you for your suggestion. How can I edit the setup.py? Please find my setup.py code below:          
                                                                                          
`from setuptools import find_packages, setup
package_name = 'dl_demo'
setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['test'])
   ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
               'pub_sub = dl_demo.demo_in_ros:main', 
        ],
    },
)`

Comment: @billy Thank you for your help. I got the errors below with three different importing items: 1) `from dl_demo.dl_demo.utils import common_utils`, Error: `File "/home/abbas/ros2demo_ws/install/dl_demo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dl_demo/demo_in_ros.py", line 33, in <module> from dl_demo.utils import common_utils ModuleNotFoundError: No module named dl_demo.dl_demo'` , 2) `from dl_demo.utils import common_utils`, Error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dl_demo.utils'` , 3) `from .utils import common_utils`, Error: `No module named 'dl_demo.utils'`   Any idea to solve this issue?